# How to let Flink flush last line to sink when producer(kafka) does not produce new line

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

when my Flink program is in event time mode, sink will not get last line(say line A). If I feed new line(line B) to Flink, I will get the line A, but I still cann't get the line b.

```scala
    val env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment
    env.setParallelism(1)
    env.enableCheckpointing(5000, CheckpointingMode.EXACTLY_ONCE)
    env.setStreamTimeCharacteristic(TimeCharacteristic.EventTime)

    val properties = new Properties()
    properties.setProperty("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")
    properties.setProperty("group.id", "test")

    val consumer = new FlinkKafkaConsumer[String]("topic", new SimpleStringSchema(), properties)

    val stream: DataStream[String] = env.addSource(consumer).setParallelism(1)

    stream.map { m =>
      val result = JSON.parseFull(m).asInstanceOf[Some[Map[String, Any]]].get
      val msg = result("message").asInstanceOf[String]
      val num = parseMessage(msg)
      val key = s"${num.zoneId} ${num.subZoneId}"
      (key, num, num.onlineNum)
    }.filter { data =>
      data._2.subZoneId == 301 && data._2.zoneId == 5002
    }.assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(new MyTimestampExtractor()).keyBy(0)
      .window(TumblingEventTimeWindows.of(Time.seconds(1)))
        .allowedLateness(Time.minutes(1))
      .maxBy(2).addSink { v =>
      System.out.println(s"${v._2.time} ${v._1}: ${v._2.onlineNum} ")
    }
```

```scala
class MyTimestampExtractor() extends AscendingTimestampExtractor[(String, OnlineNum, Int)](){
  val byMinute = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:SS")
  override def extractAscendingTimestamp(element: (String, OnlineNum, Int)): Long = {
    val dateTimeString =  element._2.date + " " + element._2.time
    val c1 = byMinute.parse(dateTimeString).getTime
    if ( element._2.time.contains("22:59") && element._2.subZoneId == 301){
      //System.out.println(s"${element._2.time} ${element._1}: ${element._2.onlineNum} ")
      // System.out.println(s"${element._2.time} ${c1 - getCurrentWatermark.getTimestamp}")
    }

    // System.out.println(s"${element._2.time} ${c1} ${c1 - getCurrentWatermark.getTimestamp}")
    return c1
  }
}
```

data sample:

```
01:01:14 5002 301: 29 
01:01:36 5002 301: 27 
01:02:05 5002 301: 27 
01:02:31 5002 301: 29 
01:03:02 5002 301: 29 
01:03:50 5002 301: 29 
01:04:52 5002 301: 29 
01:07:24 5002 301: 26 
01:09:28 5002 301: 21 
01:11:04 5002 301: 22 
01:12:11 5002 301: 24 
01:13:54 5002 301: 23 
01:15:13 5002 301: 22 
01:16:04 5002 301: 19 (I can not get this line )
```

Then I push new line to Flink(via kafka)

```
01:17:28 5002 301: 15
```

I will get `01:16:04 5002 301: 19`, but `01:17:28 5002 301: 15` may be held in Flink.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this happens because it's event time and the event's timestamp is used to measure the flow of time for windows.

In such case, when only one event is in the window Flink does not know that the window should be omitted. For this reason, when You add next event, the previous window is closed and elements are emitted (in your case 19), but then again next window is created (in your case 15).

Probably the best idea in such case is to add custom `ProcessingTimeTrigger` which will basically allow You to emit the window after some time has flown, no matter if the events are flowing or not. You can find info about Trigger in the [documentation](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/stream/operators/windows.html#built-in-and-custom-triggers).

Comment: Thanks. I think that is how Flink event time works. But I don't find the proof in the Flink source code. Would you find that piece of code? And adding a custom `ProcessingTimeTrigger` is a solution but it causes an another problem that Flink don't aggregate the result.

Comment: Yeah, this is exactly how event time is supposed to work. Could You please clarify what do You mean about aggregating the result ?

Answer (score 0):

What is the final solution, please? I also encountered a similar situation, which can be solved by using new Watermark(System.CurrtTimeMillis()), but it does not seem to fit the purpose of Watermark. Isn't this a common problem, or are application developers deliberately ignoring it and communities ignoring it?

[Why not on-time when I consumed kafka message using flink streaming sql group by TUMBLE(rowtime)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55779711/why-not-on-time-when-i-consumed-kafka-message-using-flink-streaming-sql-group-by#)

Comment: If you just want the last line,ProcessingTimerTrigger is the solution.

Comment: The key problem is that when retrieving data from the SocketServer data source, the default trigger(EventTimeTrigger) is also used, and there is no similar problem with the last line.  https://github.com/shaozhipeng/flink-quickstart/blob/master/src/main/java/me/icocoro/quickstart/streaming/sql/SQLTester.java

Comment: what is the data source that causes your problem?

Comment: FlinkKafkaConsumer011

Comment: That's the problem. I think ProcessingTimerTrigger is the only way to get what you want so far.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you. Today, I've read the EventTimeTrigger source code and found that only onElement and onEventTime have a chance to TriggerResult.FIRE. It seems that as long as the interval between two eventtimes is too large, larger than the time window interval, or there is no new data before the end time of the window arrives (neither element(onElement) nor eventtime(onEventtime)), then the last window output must not be timely or non-real-time, and must wait for the new data stream to connect.

Comment: Nice job. The detail you given is very useful for others to know why.

Answer (score 0):

config tableEnv let it emit early:

```
 TableConfig config = bbTableEnv.getConfig();
    config.getConfiguration().setBoolean("table.exec.emit.early-fire.enabled", true);
    config.getConfiguration().setString("table.exec.emit.early-fire.delay", "1s");
```